# How to Customise TextInputEditText with a CountryCode Picker

Tags: android, android-layout, material-ui, android-textinputlayout

How to achieve this?
[Photo Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl1dG.jpg)
I am not able to add the coutrycode picker inside TextInputEditText. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is Sample

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp">

    <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
        android:id="@+id/ccp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
        app:ccpDialog_textColor="@color/black"
        app:ccp_arrowColor="@color/textColorDark"
        app:ccp_autoDetectCountry="true"
        app:ccp_contentColor="@color/textColorLight"
        app:ccp_showFlag="false"
        app:ccp_showFullName="false"
        app:ccp_showNameCode="false"
        app:ccp_showPhoneCode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_phone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout_phone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_subtitle_phone_auth" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/textColorLight"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```